# React Native bottom tab navigator - Android screen reader only selects tab label and not tab icon as well

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a bottom tab navigator from react navigation.

Previously, when you had the screen reader on, both the text and the icon of each tab could be selected as one container.
[Here we see both the icon and label being selected as one container for the screen reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJXxE.png)

After upgrading to RN 0.69 from 0.68, only the text in the tab bar is selectable. How can I make both the icon and text selectable as one container? If I add an accessibility label to the tab bar icon, the whole container can be selected again, but that requires that we add a label.

Comment: It's too bad they changed the behavior but the old behavior and the new behavior both appear to be accessible (at least from the minimal information here - if you had a working example, I could test it to confirm). Whether a screen reader is running or not, when you `tab` to the navigator, is there a visible focus border around just the text? If you navigate with the down arrow using a screen reader (walking the DOM), can you get to both the icon and the text separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for responding. Really appreciate it!

I hadn't done the correct research. In the documentation , it says that theres is a prop which you can add to the whole tab bar.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaraccessibilitylabel

After adding this, the container (both the tab icon and text) was selectable as one container. It is just strange that this behaviour worked before without adding that prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom tab bar and add accessibility as you wish in each tab bar item like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar/>}>
    <Tab.Screen .../>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thank you for response, i considered this solution but did not go with it since this behavior was implemented by using the tabbaraccessibilitylabel prop instead, this let me skip the creation of a whole new custom component! Thank you again for response

Comment: You're welcome :D, Just mark your answer as a correct one to make everyone know the right answer and upvote mine :D